# A word to describe a person who has gone astray

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

What is a person who has gone astray called?

This basically refers to the person who is not following the path to success but has gone astray . For instance these lines from the psalm of life depict a person who has gone astray :
"A forlorn and shipwrecked brother "

Comment: Only noun I can think of is "lost soul."

Comment: The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Usually, a person who has gone astray is called a *stray*.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox but if a kid brings home a stray, the parents would be surprised if it were a human instead of a cat or dog :P

Comment: As evidenced by the only answer posted thus far, *He has gone astray* would normally be understood as a somewhat metaphoric usage meaning *He's started doing things that are undesirable / harmful to his future wellbeing*, rather than a straightforward literal statement about the fact that he's (accidentally) deviated from his intended (spatial) route to get from from point A to point B.

Comment: *We are poor little lambs, who have gone astray, bah, bah, bah.*

Answer (score 0):

A person can **"go off the rails"**, which means they may have started to behave out of line, in an unacceptable way, or they are not conforming or performing to the standards expected of them (by society).

*Example:* If a child starts skipping school and falls in with a bad crowd, you might say they have gone off the rails.